# Can I use a plug rated for a DC circuit in a low voltage AC circuit?

Tags: voltage, ac, dc, plug

I have an spare 2-conductor plug rated for 12VDC at 5A from an old project.  I’m now working on a Class II low voltage (24VAC) projet for which I need just such a plug.  Is the plug rated for the DC circuit suitable for this, or do I need to look for a plug rated for an AC circuit?

(Since I was asked for a picture, here’s a link to the plug in question: https://www.radioshack.com/products/enercell-2-conductor-accessory-cables)

Comment: Connector and switch ratings are usually higher for AC than for DC due to the arc-extinguishing that happens at zero crossings, but unless you can find a datasheet that gives AC ratings I can't in good conscience say yes to the questions. I can, however, say "probably".